# mac automation by passing message to 'configure'

Tags: c, macos, debugging, gdb, configure

I installed 'gdb' to debug my C program in mac with VS Code.
When I typed "brew install gdb", it told me to follow the instructions in  https://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/BuildingOnDarwin to give permission to gdb.
But there is one sentence that I have no idea how to follow.
The sentence is :

> If you plan to build gdb frequently, this step can be automated by **passing** *--enable-codesign=gdb-cert* (assuming, again, that *gdb-cert* is the name of the certificate) **to *configure*.**

How can I pass the message to the *configure*? What is the 'configure' in mac terminal?? I'm using Catalina and zsh. please help!